# OSM routing (OSRM): do I need to duplicate all data for different profiles?

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

I use OSRM and would like to allow the user to select from different routing profiles (e.g. car / foot). The documentation states that I can define the profile during the extract and prepare process. Does this mean that I have to run seperate instances for each profile, each with its own .osrm file? (this is an issue because I run it for a dataset covering large areas (~100GB).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as of today OSRM doesn't support multiple profiles.